# MySQL Log shows error from a long time ago when importing batch today

Tags: mysql, batch-file, logging

Today I'm trying to import a batch file using SQLyog, however I'm getting the following error:

```
Query:       
CREATE TABLE 'developer' (
'ID' bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'username' tinytext NOT NULL,
'password' text NOT NULL,
'email' text NOT NULL,
'active' tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
'role' tinytext,
'defaultConfig' bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ('ID'),
FULLTEXT KEY 'User' ('username')
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Error occured at:2014-02-18 08:32:47
Line no.:46
Error Code: 1214 - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes
```

`developer` is not a table I'm trying to do anything with in my batch file, it even belongs to another db.

Actually 2014-02-18 was the date when I installed MySQL for the first time, I installed the most up to date version of MySQL at that time. However, a couple of weeks ago I downgraded MySQL in my machine to Version 6.6.5.0, I'm not sure if that has screwed things up.

I would like to get rid of this problem and import the sql batch file.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) FULLTEXT indexes can only be created on tables with the mylsam engine.

Change your engine like this and try again:

```
CREATE TABLE 'developer' (
'ID' bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'username' tinytext NOT NULL,
'password' text NOT NULL,
'email' text NOT NULL,
'active' tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
'role' tinytext,
'defaultConfig' bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ('ID'),
FULLTEXT KEY 'User' ('username')
) ENGINE=MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and if the table is already created then try to alter it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE <table name> ENGINE = [MYISAM]
```

Comment: I'd rather remove the fulltext index than change the engine

Comment: @RafaelDiaz:- Yes that is also one option but the error which you have reported is because of the above reason. Although you have an option of remving the index!

Comment: But I can't remove it, when I run: `ALTER TABLE developer DROP INDEX User;` it returns: `Can't DROP 'User'; check that column/key exists
`

Comment: @RafaelDiaz:- This error means that you are trying to delete a key which is being used by another table. Also I think the index is not created since you were receiving the error while creating the table so the error is fine. I think you have to remove it from the definition of the table.

Comment: I have imported the schema for `developer` again, there's no freetext index now, however I'm still getting that error when importing the batch file

Comment: @RafaelDiaz:- I am quite sure that you have got some reference of this key somewhere in your db. You have to check that. Else I would suggest you to change the engine!

Comment: The batch file I'm trying to import has nothing to do with the `developer` table

Comment: `ALTER TABLE developer ENGINE=MyISAM;` doesn't fix the problem

Comment: @RafaelDiaz:- Does the developer table exists in your database? If yes then check what does this return SHOW INDEX FROM developer ?

Comment: @RafaelDiaz:- Then probably you can try to drop your table by deleting its all reference and then create your table again without the FULLTEXT index and your problem will be resolved! :)

Comment: That's what I've tried ten minutes ago, please see my comment: I have imported the schema for developer again, there's no freetext index now, however I'm still getting that error when importing the batch file –

Comment: That includes a `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS developer;`

Comment: @RafaelDiaz:- And after the drop and create table when you execute this SHOW INDEX FROM developer ....what does this return?

Comment: -<data>
-<row>
<Table>developer</Table>
<Non_unique>0</Non_unique>
<Key_name>PRIMARY</Key_name>
<Seq_in_index>1</Seq_in_index>
<Column_name>ID</Column_name>
<Collation>A</Collation>
<Cardinality>1</Cardinality>
<Sub_part>(NULL)</Sub_part>
<Packed>(NULL)</Packed>
<Null/>
<Index_type>BTREE</Index_type>
<Comment/>
<Index_comment/>
</row>
</data>